# find_package(Boost) returns empty Boost_LIBRARIES

Tags: boost

cmake version 3.8.2

I have a strange problem. When I do `find_package(Boost)`, then the Boost_LIBRARIES is empty. But when I do `find_package(Boost REQUIRED filesystem)`, the Boost_LIBRARIES variable shows the corresponding libraries.

In both the cases, Boost is found, because it shows that the Boost version is 1.64.

with REQUIRED

```
-- Boost version: 1.64.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   system
       Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: /usr/local/include
       OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS: /usr/local/include;/usr/local/include/opencv
       Boost_LIBRARIES: /usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem.so;/usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so
       OpenCV_LIBRARIES: opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_shape;opencv_stitching;opencv_superres;opencv_video;opencv_videoio;opencv_videostab
```

Without REQUIRED

```
-- Boost version: 1.64.0
       Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: /usr/local/include
       OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS: /usr/local/include;/usr/local/include/opencv
       Boost_LIBRARIES: 
       OpenCV_LIBRARIES: opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_shape;opencv_stitching;opencv_superres;opencv_video;opencv_videoio;opencv_videostab
```

Shouldnt the boost libraries, also show just the libraries and not the whole path, like the opencv?

Although I have the program_options in the same folder, the Boost cannot find it and cmake throws an error.

```
  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_program_options
```

Please see the ll.

```
truncated ll output.....
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1558464 Aug 12 06:23 /usr/local/lib/libboost_program_options.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      34 Aug 12 06:23 /usr/local/lib/libboost_program_options.so -> libboost_program_options.so.1.64.0*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  658920 Aug 12 06:23 /usr/local/lib/libboost_program_options.so.1.64.0*
```

Answer (score 3):

No matter REQUIRED is present or not, it's always empty.

Mac High Sierra/CMake 3.10.1.

It seems a bug of FindBoost.cmake

Comment: Does cmake  show the Boost version like Boost version: 1.64.0? By the way, you should write your post in the comment as its not an answer.

Comment: @infoclogged Yes. CMake found the right boost version and got it shown in console.

Comment: This might be the answer.

Comment: Now I am using 1.66 and still, I have this issue.

Comment: @neckTwi I dont have this problem, when I write the REQUIRED keyword. The boost libraries are not found "only" when I dont write the REQUIRED keyword.

Comment: yep, I didn't mention the component

Comment: I have the same issue of it being empty with 1.67 and MacOS Mojave<br/><code>cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
...
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)


include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

FIND_PACKAGE(Boost REQUIRED)

MESSAGE("Boost information:")
MESSAGE("  Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
MESSAGE("  Boost_LIBRARIES: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
</code>
add_executable(WSUsingWSPP main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(WSUsingWSPP ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

Comment: Same issue here with macOS and homebrew installed boost.

Comment: This is so weird, I have the same problem with cmake version 3.15.1

Comment: same issue. ubuntu18.04 arm with libboost-dev-all installed and cmake3.10